# ブラウザで開いてるページの ajax 通信の内容を自動でローカルファイルに残したい

Tags: javascript, html5, google-chrome

ウェブアプリの ajax 通信の内容を自動でローカルファイル等にダンプしたいです

tcpdump で特定のドメインIPがソースのパケットをファイルにダンプすればできなくはなさそうですが
HTTP ヘッダとかを分離しないといけないので大変です

chrome の開発ツールで
ネットワーク > XHR > Name が特定のエンドポイント
の場合のレスポンスボディだけを
延々とファイルに出力し続けるような簡単な方法はないでしょうか

通信するのは HTML5 (JavaScript) なのでそこに割り込むような
chrome extension だったりブックマークレットだったりでもいいし
ブラウザプラグインでも　パケットキャプチャツールでも　実現方法は何でもいいです

---

ブラウジングしながら特定のレスポンスが出たのをトリガーにして処理するようなプログラムを書きたいので、とにかく手動操作なしでローカル上のプログラムからレスポンスを読める状態にしたいorレスポンスを渡したいです

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ブラウジングしながら特定のレスポンスが出たのをトリガーにして処理するようなプログラムを書きたい

と言うことでしたら、 [puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer) などを利用して、 [Chrome DevTools Protocol の Fetch ドメイン](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Fetch/) を直叩きして、ブラウザ内の通信を片っ端から割り込んで、 ヘッダーやボディを横取りしてしまうのが、色々潰しがきいてオススメです。

以下の node.js を使った例では、 body バイナリを UTF-8 文字列にしてコンソールに出力していますが、もちろんファイルに保存する事も可能です。
上記目的だと、むしろファイルに保存しない方が良いのでは？と想像しています。

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, defaultViewport: null });
    const page = (await browser.pages())[0];
    try {
        const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
        await client.send('Fetch.enable', { 'patterns': [{ 'urlPattern': '*', 'requestStage': 'Response' }] });
        client.on('Fetch.requestPaused', async (requestEvent) => {
            const { requestId, responseStatusCode, responseHeaders } = requestEvent;
            try {
                if (!responseStatusCode) throw `responseStatusCode: ${responseStatusCode}`;
                const response = await client.send('Fetch.getResponseBody', { requestId });

                // dump response body
                if (response.base64Encoded) {
                    console.log(new Buffer(response.body, 'base64').toString('utf-8'));
                } else {
                    console.log(response.body);
                }

                await client.send('Fetch.fulfillRequest', { requestId, responseCode: responseStatusCode, responseHeaders, 'body': response.body });
            } catch {
                await client.send('Fetch.continueRequest', { requestId });
            }
        });

        // wait for close
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => page.on('close', resolve));
    } finally {
        (await browser.pages()).forEach(p => p.close());
        browser.close();
    }
})();
```

`client.send('Fetch.enable', ...);` のところで、 [urlPattern](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Fetch/#type-RequestPattern) を適切に設定してあげれば、 特定のエンドポイントだけハンドリングすることができます。

上記例では、 Chrome をバンドルしている puppeteer を使いましたが、 例えば別途インストール済みの Chrome を使うなら [puppeteer-core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-core) を使うとか、 他の言語のバインディングを使うなどと言った選択肢があります。

Chrome DevTools Protocol ないし Remote Debugging Protocol はある程度標準化された仕様なので、 puppeteer 以外でも、 Selenium v4 など他のツールからも利用可能です。

Comment: 具体的な応用例として、 [ブラウザ操作中の通信の内容をローカルファイルに自動で片っ端から保存していく](https://aquasoftware.net/blog/?p=1989) 例を記事にまとめたので、ご参考まで。

Answer (score 2):

[mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/)の[アドオン機能](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/addons-overview/)で実現できるかと思います。

例)
`save_body.py`:

```py
import mitmproxy
def response(flow):
    if flow.request.pretty_url.startswith("https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/special/coronavirus/data/") and flow.response.headers["content-type"].startswith("application/json"):
        with open("responses.txt","ab") as f:
            f.write(flow.response.content)
```

確認手順:
`mitmdump`コマンドでプロキシサーバを起動し、

```
mitmdump -s save_body.py
```

`mitmproxy` をプロキシに設定したウェブブラウザで https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/special/coronavirus/data/ へアクセス。

---

※ Pythonの文法を知らないので次を参考にしました:

- [Save body response from specific URL to file and decode it using mitmproxy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48158427/4506703) - Stack Overflow

Comment: すんなり動けばやりたいことできそうだったんですが。。。https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/5015　こちらと同じ問題で windows 上でうまく動きませんでした

Comment: @chico そちらと同じ問題であれば、 [Visual Studio 2015 の Visual C++ 再頒布可能パッケージ](https://www.microsoft.com/ja-JP/download/details.aspx?id=48145) をインストールすることで利用できるようになる、とあるように読めます。

Answer (score 0):

DevToolsはHARファイルのエクスポート・インポートが可能です。
延々と出力することは出来ないですが、一定時間キャプチャしてエクスポートすることで十分であれば試してみてください。

[トラブルシューティング用のHARファイルの生成](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/ja/articles/204410413-%E3%83%88%E3%83%A9%E3%83%96%E3%83%AB%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E7%94%A8%E3%81%AEHAR%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AE%E7%94%9F%E6%88%90)

> 1. Google Chromeを開き、問題が発生しているページに移動します。
> 2. 縦の省略符号ボタンを探して、「その他のツール」>「デベロッパーツール」を選択します。
> 3. 開いたパネルから、「Network」タブを選択します。
> 4. タブの左端にある丸い記録（）ボタンを探して、ボタンが赤くなっていることを確かめます。ボタンが灰色になっている場合、1回クリックして記録を開始します。
> 5. 「Preserve log」ボックスをチェックします。
> 6. Clearボタン（）をクリックして、「Network」タブから既存のログをすべて消去します。
> 7. ネットワークリクエストが記録されている間に、先ほど発生した問題を再現します。
>    8.問題を再現できたら、Chromeの場合は「Download」をクリックします。ファイルに次の名前を付けてコンピュータに保存します：「HAR with Content」

Comment: ブラウジングしながら特定のレスポンスが出たのをトリガーにして処理するようなプログラムを書きたいので、とにかく手動操作なしでローカル上のプログラムからレスポンスを読める状態にしたいorレスポンスを渡したいのです

Comment: それは質問に追加すべき情報では。

Comment: 申し訳ないです。「延々とファイルに出力し続ける方法」とかいたので十分かと思っていました。追記しました

Answer (score 0):

chrome://net-export/
これを使うのはどうですか？

Comment: 使ってみたんですがデフォルトではヘッダのみしか記録されず、row データも含むとすと暗号化された文字列が出力されるだけで、レスポンス JSON に相当するようなものは見当たりませんでした。

Answer (score 0):

Windowsだったら、Fiddlerというツールはどうでしょう。

https://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddler-classic

Comment: さわってみたんですがプログラマブルな部分はパケットのカスタマイズぐらいで、データによって音を鳴らしたり任意のコードを実行できるわけではないようです。あとたまってる内容をUI上から保存はできるんですが操作せずにファイルに追記し続ける方法もよくわかりませんでした