# chrome ディベロッパツールのカスタマイズ方法

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

[ブラウザで開いてるページの ajax 通信の内容をローカルファイルに残したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/76026)

前回の質問でも同様の質問をしたんですが
ブラウジング中のパケットをキャプチャして
特定の通信内容が現れたらアラートを鳴らしたりするようなツールを作りたいです

---

以前やってたゲームでこんな拡張機能があって

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome%E9%8E%AE%E5%AE%88%E5%BA%9C/hcjpbcmhppmlohedljpeagnjplpjonhc?hl=ja

ディベロッパーツール自体にメニューを追加して
通信パケット内容を覗き見て内容によって表示を変えるみたいになっています

ディベロッパーツールにメニューを追加したり
パケット情報を取得したりするのってどういう技術でできるんでしょうか

ディベロッパーツールカスタマイズとかで調べてもでてこないので
入門的な記事やドキュメント等を紹介をしていただけると助かります

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome の拡張機能の中で開発者ツールの拡張が可能です。
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/devtools/