# ブラウザのリクエストを監視して特定のリソースを自動保存したい

Tags: google-chrome, http, firefox, https, proxy

よろしくお願いします。

ブラウザ(Firefox/Chromeなど)の拡張機能かproxyサーバで、
ブラウザが事前に正規表現などで指定したアドレスにアクセスすると
そのリソースを自動的にファイルとして保存する方法を探しています。

```
条件: https://example.net/address/to/(image-\d+.jpg)
保存: /path/to/file/\1
```

と指定しておくと

```
https://example.net/address/to/image-001.jpg
```

などにアクセスすると`image-001.jpg`が自動的に保存されるイメージです。

mitmproxyと云うものを見つけて手動で保存はできそうなのですが自動化できると助かります。

Comment: [ブラウザで開いてるページの ajax 通信の内容を自動でローカルファイルに残したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/76026/%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A6%E3%82%B6%E3%81%A7%E9%96%8B%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6%E3%82%8B%E3%83%9A%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%81%AE-ajax-%E9%80%9A%E4%BF%A1%E3%81%AE%E5%86%85%E5%AE%B9%E3%82%92%E8%87%AA%E5%8B%95%E3%81%A7%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AB%E3%83%AB%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AB%E6%AE%8B%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84/78265#78265)
こちらを参考にアドオンを作ることで目的を達しました。